# Passing arguments(with spaces) to batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Unable to receive complete parameter in a single argument.

**Code**

```
 string startupPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
 string bat = startupPath + @"\util.bat";
 var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.FileName = @bat;  
 psi.Verb = "runas";
 psi.Arguments = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/bin/x64" +"param2";
 psi.UseShellExecute = true;  
 Process.Start(psi);
```

Batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.

echo %~1 //this prints "C:/Program Files"

echo %1% //this prints "C:/Program Files"

echo %*  //this prints C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/bin/x64 param2


cd %1%
echo "done"

ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT
```

I want to receive the two params in 2 different variables like %1% and %2%.
I can comma separate them while sending and fetch it on the batch file. But, want to make this work!

Comment: Try `psi.Arguments = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/bin/x64\"  param2";`

Comment: ...not the solution, but: `%1%` is wrong, it's `%1`!

Comment: @aschipfl : May be wrong! but try it. It prints the same.

Comment: It only works so long as the second percent sign is ignored. Would not work in a for loop for example: `for %%a in (%1%) do echo %%a`

Comment: `psi.Arguments = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64\" \"param2\""`